# How to calculate the PACF of a time series using provided regressions?

Tags: time-series, acf-pacf

I have been provided a table of regressions of an AR(1) model and asked to calculate the PACF. I know that the PACF is the additional information about the process y_t accounting for the previous lags. So PACF(1)=ACF(1)=0.6933. But I'm not sure how to calculate the other PACFs?

I can't find a formula or explanation anywhere online, I know its probably going to be quite simple.

Any help is appreciated

[image]